# What is the canonical way to support navigators in tabs in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm interested in determining if there is a "canonical" way to have the `Navigator` and `TabBarIOS` place nice together. One way I could see is to have a `Navigator` per instance of a tab view. For example, we could have 2 tabs with each tab having a navigator:

```
<TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS.Item
    title="Tab 1"
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tab1'}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'tab1' }) }
  >
    <Navigator
      renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
        <Text>Scene 1</text>
      }
    />
  </TabBarIOS.Item>

  <TabBarIOS.Item
    title="Tab 2"
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tab2'}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'tab2' }) }
  >
    <Navigator
      renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
        <Text>Scene 2</text>
      }
    />
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
</TabBarIOS>
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the recommended way of doing this. Any suggestion as to how to handle this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern is correct: a stack navigator for each tab. It's the same as if you were doing it natively in UIKit, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Appreciate it. My only concern was if one would see a momentary "glitch" in the navigator title as the data of a tab was loading. Could potentially work around that in that case. Thanks again.